# Why do I get downloads from the US even though my app is only available in the German Play Store?

Tags: firebase, google-play

I recently released my quiz app in the german Play Store and I get some impressions/downloads from the US which is odd since it should not be visible to the Play Store there. I am using Firebase authentication and I also see that some users authenticate but in my database they don't have an account (username, avatar etc.) which also can't be because after you login with Google you get to a page where you can choose your username and in the second you reach to this site, a user document will be automatically created, but in some cases it does not get created.

I noticed this behavior since my app was in beta testing.

Is it a normal behavior that there are some users who can see and are able to download an app that is usually only available in one country?

Answer (score 1):

It can happen because google play console generates pre-launch reports for your app, so I think they use dummy accounts to login into your application. It can also happen when you submit an update to your app and it goes through a review process.